# Not granting permission because it was previously installed without?

Tags: adb, permissions

An app i installed fails at startup, in the logs i see this permission problem:

```
Not granting permission android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION to package com.nianticlabs.pokemongo because it was previously installed without
```

and

```
Ignoring duplicate uses-permissions/uses-permissions-sdk-m: android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in package: com.nianticlabs.pokemongo at: Binary XML file line #35
```

My phone is a Fairphone2, it runs Android 7.1.2
Buildnumber 18.09.2
Kernel-version 3.4.0-perf-geaadfcc5a2djenkins@lxc-slave05 #1 dd:20180928

The app in question is Pokemon go.

I have wiped and factory reset my phone at least 3 times, had the battery out and everything.

Is there any way to fix the permission problem via ADB?

Comment: The second message can probably be ignored, as it details a mistake in the app's AndroidManifest.xml file. To address the first one, could you try executing `pm grant com.nianticlabs.pokemongo android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` after running `adb shell`?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman if only, trying  to grant the permissions via adb *causes* the warnings. Is there any way i can alter the AndriodManifest.xml?